# Accessing classic resources in multiple subscriptions using AzureClassicRunAsAccount

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to access Classic Azure resources present in Multiple subscriptions in my Azure powershell Runbook, I use AzureClassicRunAsAccount For accessing the resources in my subscription. For ARM resources which use AzureRunAsAccount I understand a spn is created and giving access to the spn on a different subscription will let the runbook access it. But how do I do the same for ClassicRunAsAccount, this doesn't have an Spn created right ?

Comment: Azure classic resource rest api(Windows Azure Service Management API) uses X509 client certificates for authentication. So AzureClassicRunAsAccount will not create spn and it will create a management certificate in the subscription. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-security-overview#azure-classic-run-as-account and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-windows-azure-service-management-api/

Comment: Do you have any update?